# The field class must be a number on selecting Multiple DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am binding drop down as

Model Side

```
public Registration()
    {            
        Availableclass = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    [Display(Name = "Class")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select {0}.")]
    public Nullable<int> ClassId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Availableclass { get; set; }
```

Controller Side

```
 public ActionResult RegisterTutor()
    {         
        var Class = GetClasses();
        var model = new Registration {Availableclass = Class };
        return View(model);
    }    
    public IList<SelectListItem> GetClasses()
    {           
        var Class = db.Classes
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ClassName, Value = x.ClassId.ToString() })
            .ToList();            
        return Class;
    }
```

View Side

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClassId, Model.Availableclass, new { @multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })            
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassId)
```

But when I select Multiple in drop down It is showing validation as *The field class must be a number*

[image]

***How can I get rid of this validation and also let me know how can I pass multiple selection data of drop down on Controller Side***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your property type is a nullable int, where it can store either `null` or a single int value.

When you use `DropDownListFor` it generates the data attributes needed for client side validation to validate a single number value. For multi select control, the selected value will be an array (of selected value), hence getting the error.

For multi select, your property should be a collection type.

```
public int?[] ClassId { get; set; }
```

I do not think there is any reason to use nullable int in this case since it is a collection. You can use non nullable int

```
public int[] ClassIds{ get; set; }
```